# SQL Could not fetch records

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

I'm trying to output a specific record into .csv based on the demands of the user. So far, I'm able to get the .csv to work, but now that I'm trying to get a record from the form, I keep getting the message that it could not fetch my sql records.

Yes you might say that putting my php code at the top of the page might be a problem, but the reason why I put it there is to avoid having the html tags printed into the .csv file as well.

Here is my current code:

```
    <?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $material = $_POST['materials'];
        mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pw');
        mysql_select_db ("db");
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT " . $material . " FROM materials"); 
            if (!$result) 
                die('Couldn\'t fetch records'); 

        $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result); 
        $headers = array(); 

            for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
                {     
                    $headers[] = mysql_field_name($result , $i); 
                } 

        $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w'); 

            if ($fp && $result) 
                {     
                     header('Content-Type: text/csv');
                     header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');
                     header('Pragma: no-cache');    
                     header('Expires: 0');
                     fputcsv($fp, $headers); 

                     while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
                        {
                            fputcsv($fp, array_values($row)); 
                        }
                     die; 
                } 

    }

?>

<h1>Generate Reports</h1>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="create" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Materials</strong></td>

<?php
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pw');
    mysql_select_db ("db");
    $sql = "SELECT material_name FROM materials";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    echo "<td><select name='materials'>";

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['material_name'] . "'>" . 
            $row['material_name'] . "</option>";
        }

    echo "</select></td></tr> ";

    $sql2 = "SELECT location_name From locations";
    $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);

?>


                <td><strong>Locations</strong></td>
<?php

    echo "<td><select name='locations'>";
    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) 
        {
            echo "<option value='" . $row2['location_name'] . "'>" . 
            $row2['location_name'] . "</option>";
        }   

    echo "</select></td></tr>";

?>
    <tr>
        <td><button name="submit" type=submit>Generate</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: The sql JOIN? I don't get what you mean. Be more specific.

Comment: change `mysql_fetch_row` to `mysql_fetch_array` in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to get the record for the particular material from the table right??

if you use -

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT " . $material . " FROM materials");
```

this line doesn't seems good.. actually to select the material you must have the where clause and at the place for variable $material you need to pass the column u want to select or * for all the columns. your query may be like this -

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM materials where Material_Name = ".$material);
```

now it will return you all the records from the material table where the material name is the value you passed.

Comment: I guess I forgot to put the "where" part, but it still doesn't retrieve the values from the form!

Comment: Nvm, I had a typo. Worked fine :)

Comment: see variable $material has the material name right?? lets consider you have entered the material name 'XXX' then what query where execute in your case??

that is - 
**select XXX from material**

but in actually the query will be 

**Select * from material where material_name = XXX** 

so please change the query also